# Dynamic column values based on other values, like in Excel

Tags: c#, mysql

Inside of my system I have a main DataTable, and a sub DataTable. These are DataTables populated through a mySQL server

Based on a unique identifier, the two are linked.

using SQL, if the user has selected row 1, with ID 1 in the main table, all entries which are associated with that ID are pulled into the sub table.

As an example; If the user selected "Toms grocery store", with the unique ID 23, then the system would look for all rows associated with ID 23 in a seperate table in order to return all of the items "Toms grocery store" sells and populate the subtable.

What i'd like to do is have a value set on the main table which will be a sort of total, based on what's been pulled to the subtable. so, if each item sold in Toms grocery store had a price associated with it, then i'd like to have a line in the main table for Toms grocery indicating what the total cost is of all of those items combined. for a total net worth.

This would be easy to do in excel, but does anyone know how to do this in mySQL/c# ?

Comment: I would not suggest it because the values in the sub tables could change and if your logic is not correct it may miss some of the values and then the totals in the main table will no longer be correct.  You can do those types of queries in real time (if your db is designed properly and your queries are well written it should come back quickly)

Comment: but what would that sql  look like? I'm not sure how to set the value based on a query

Comment: Can you post your actual table structures?  It would be much eaiser to write a query to show you that.  Otherwise you can lookup SQL Joins and Group By.